# Memory leak on XMLHttpRequest send() method

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to send a file with an XMLHttpRequest to a Flask server.
Basically this is what I do:

```
<!-- this is the HTML input element -->
<input name="file" type="file" onchange="sendBlob(this.files[0])" multiple>

function sendBlob(file)
{
    var chunkSize = 500000000; // 500 MB

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var blob = file.slice(0, chunkSize, "application/octet-stream");

    xhr.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/get_layout/");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
            console.log("blob successfully sent.");
    }

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Content-Name", "blob");

    xhr.send(blob);
}
```

[memory staus before xhr.send()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t70mz.png)

This function actually works and send the file to the server successfully, but it increases RAM memory without releasing it.
In particular, it grows exactly by 500 MB, that it's the size of the blob that I'm sending.

[memory staus after xhr.send()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG5Qi.png)

What can the problem be?
I already know that Javascript has a garbage collector, but it seems that it doesn't collect the xhr object once the request is done (i.e. the server returned a 200 status code).

If I close my web browser after this process, memory is released.
I can't understand why this is happening.

Thanks

Comment: With chrome is the same?

Comment: I tried also with Chrome and it behaves in the same way.

Comment: Try adding `delete xhr` on `onreadystatechange`

Comment: I also tried that line of code, but nothing changed.

Comment: @ariel after some more accurate tests, I found out that this issue is present only on Firefox. With both Chrome and Chromium this situation doesn't happen. What does this could mean?

Comment: I imagine something is making the closure alive. Try instead of anonymous function `onchange="sendBlob(this.files[0])"` a named function `inputElement.addEventListener('change', changeFunction); function changeFunction() { var file = this.files[0]; ...`

Comment: Tried also this, but nothing changed.